# Recover ETH from a smart contract? - SCAMMED

Tags: recover

2I think I got scammed real bad. I watched a YouTube tutorial and deployed a smart contract using solidity and remix. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ28UUVBSKc.  However two minutes after I sent ETH from my wallet to this contract it disappeared from the contract (see attached screenshot from etherscan on the transactions.This is the created contract address: 0xBE30fb3a6b5ec4A36d790ec89BB2460047a6e42e
Is there any way to recover this ETH amount?
I would be really grateful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: This contract address, the last transaction that was done on it is 347 days ago. How did you get scammed today?

Comment: Question asked tons of time. 
- 1 - you got scammed
- 2 - never use and deploy unverified code (duh)
- 3 - take time to use the search button instead of spamming by creating a profile you'll never reuse and posting a question asked and answered dozens of times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, this was the address Imeant: https://etherscan.io/address/0xea1fc3144f0c8a3e1cf585786f043bf2045b31ea